# Объясните, пожалуйста, выбор н/нн

Tags: причастия, нн

> Всё это затёрто, зашито, заклее(н)но, отремонтирова(н)но бесчисленное количество раз.

Это причастия, верно? Приставка есть. Зависимые слова есть ("бесчисленное количество раз").
Значит, **нн**? А вот [тут](http://www.morfologija.ru/%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0/%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BE) говорят, что одна **н**. Что-то я запуталась.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Количество Н определяется зависимыми словами в случае с ***полной*** формой прилагательных и причастий. С *одной Н без зависимых слов* в этом случае получаются *прилагательные,* а *с двумя Н с зависимыми словами* — причастия.
Например: *"краше**н**ая стена" — "краше**нн**ые **хной** волосы", "жаре**н**ый пирожок" — "жаре**нн**ый в масле гусь".*

У вас же ***краткие*** формы страдательных причастий. Они пишутся с одной Н.

Comment: Здравствуйте, Артём. Примерно поняла, хотя бы с какой стороны подступиться. То есть тут причастие ещё и страдательное, поэтому одна "н"?

Comment: Здравствуйте, Юлия! ;) Главное то, что оно краткое. "Отремонтированный" полное — с НН, а "отремонтирована(о)" — краткое с Н. При этом — да, оба страдательные. Ещё примеры: прикреплено, сделано, построено. Мы же не говорим "сдела**нн**о в Китае"!